# Rebuild called changing tabs during Animation

Tags: flutter

I came across a problem trying to implement a music quizz minigame, I want to have two tabWidgets, one containing the game itself( with a countdown animated timer and buttons for the user to press), and the second tab containing the history of songs and artists.

I want the user to be able to switch between the two tabs during the play, but it's calling rebuild despite using :

```
class _GameWidgetState extends State<GameWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

@override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

I have a lot of Consumer in the build method which is very large, so I can't just copy paste it here for no overcharge, but I will post it if you don't understand the problem.

```
Consumer<GameController>(
          builder: (context, model, child) {
                  ...
```

I understand that rebuilding when changing tabs is a normal behavior, but I have a CircularCountDownTimer which I have taken from the package circular_countdown_timer, and the animation controller is inside the class, so when I switch tabs, the controller resets, and the countdown starts from 0 again despite the game advancing.

I am trying to override CircularCountDownTimer to change some of the methods so that I can have the AnimationController hosted on my side, so that it does not rebuild when build() is called, but I find overriding classes that have substates and subcontrollers really hard and tedious.

Is there a solution other than surclassing CircularCountDownTimer and having the countdown animation starting at a point that is controlled outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copy pasting the code of CircularCountDownTimer library, and modifying it so that the _controller is not private, so that I can use:

```
_controller.value = x;
```

When the gameWidget rebuilds, I can use this line of code to rebuild the countdown widget at a point of the animation controlled by an external countDown.